# Zebra SDK Via Hyperloop Android

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop

I am new to Hyperloop, trying to print to a bluetooth printer with the Zebra SDK from Android.

I am able to connect to the printer but when I try to get and instance of ZebraPrinter and then print an image with that instance I am told the method does not exist even though it should be(its inherited, but is clearly [documented](http://link-os.github.io/android/v2.9.2275/documentation/index.html) by Zebra). This also seems to be true of other inhertied methods as well, I have tried a few others to see what works and what doesn't.

Am I missing some kind of configuration step or something more/less obvious?

Below is my code:

```
var ZComm = require('com.zebra.sdk.comm.*'),
ZPrinter = require('com.zebra.sdk.printer.*'),
ZDevice = require('com.zebra.sdk.device.*');

var theBtMacAddress = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX";

function print(e) {
    var thePrinterConn = new ZComm.BluetoothConnection(theBtMacAddress);
    thePrinterConn.open();
    var printer = ZPrinter.ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(thePrinterConn);
    printer.printImage('/testPage.png', 0, 0);
    thePrinterConn.close();
}


$.index.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tried using `thePrinterConn.write(StringOrImageInBytes)`, maybe we can start with that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This appears to be a try-this-and-let-me-know-how-it-goes response, which belongs as a comment and not as an answer.